# Derivation of mode of Pareto distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, pareto-distribution

How do we derive the mode of a pareto distribution? Any hints would be appreciated. Should KKT conditions be used?

Comment: Have a look at these plots: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution

Comment: Since the Pareto PDF is strictly decreasing, it's just the minimum of the support, which is immediate from the definition of the distribution.

Comment: @WillVousden, why not develop that a little and make it an official answer?

Comment: @WillVousden is there no formal derivation? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution), the PDF of the Pareto distribution is
$$
f(x) = \alpha \,x_m^\alpha x^{-\alpha-1},
$$
where $x \ge x_m$, $x_m > 0$, and $\alpha > 0$.  Here, $x_m$ is the *scale parameter* of the distribution and sets a lower bound on which it's valid (note that $x_m > 0$ is required for a meaningful distribution).

We can see straight away by differentiation that $f$ is strictly decreasing:
$$
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= -(\alpha+1)\alpha \,x_m^\alpha x^{-\alpha-2} \\
&<0
\end{align}
$$

Meanwhile, the mode of $f$ is defined as $\mathop{\arg\,\max}_x f(x)$.  For a strictly decreasing function like $f$, this is simply the smallest value of $x$ on which $f$ is defined, which in this case is $x_m$.